# Sending variables to Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, mysql, variables, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my php function:

```
 function displayrecords(){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
 $QueryResult = @mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
 // more code...
```

At this point, the function prints out the retuned data in a table:

```
 echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>\n";
 while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE) {
```

And here is where the issue begins:

```
 echo "<tr><td><a class=\"open-EditRow btn btn-primary btn-mini\" 
   data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"myEditModal\" id=\"".$Row[pk_tId]."\" 
   title=\"Edit this row\" \">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
```

There are more printed `td` tags after this, but the issue is transferring the id to the modal window.  I was told this could be done with straight php and without javascript or ajax.

This is what the code looks like in the modal:

```
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
  aria-labelleby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <?php
   $id = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"groupId\" id=\"groupId\" value=\"\" />";
   $sql = "SELECT resgroup FROM restable WHERE pk_tId = '" . $id . "'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

As you will notice, the `$sql` is reading `$id` as an input tag, and therefore, it cannot find the id in the database, and thus returns nothing.  I know it starts with the anchor tag inside the echoed table above.

I need to utilize a `$_GET` (or `POST`) in the anchor tag, but I do not know where to put it. I'm guessing it should go in the `id=\"".$Row[pk_tId]."\"` , but how when php is already being used in that id?

I am a visual person, so if you could provide an example, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a bit javascript to manipulate your modal depends on which button you clicked. I think this solution will help you.

First, I supposed that there is a form inside your modal and you will submit it with your selected `id`. The modal body should be like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="//your/path/to/php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_id" id="selected_id" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Confirm your action?" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Second, I think your should remove the `data-toggle` property from your buttons, add another `data-*` property to hold your `id` and use explicit javascript call to show your modal with a bit update.

A button should be echo like this

```
echo "<tr><td><a class=\"open-EditRow btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-id=\"".$Row[pk_tId]."\" title=\"Edit this row\" \">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
```

The javascipt

```
$('.open-EditRow').click(function(){
   var selected_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('#myEditModal #selected_id').val(selected_id);
   $('#myEditModal').modal('show');
});
```

Now, in the php file declared inside the form in the modal - which receives your post data, you can `var_dump` the `$_POST`.

Comment: Would you please provide me a sample of the var_dump and how I use it? As of right now, when I click the link, the modal window no longer opens.

Comment: I did this: 
            $id = var_dump($_POST['selected_id']);
     echo $id;

It returns null. Why?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` function will display the content of the `$_POST` array. It is used just to debug and see what you received via post. You should use the value of `$_POST['selected_id']` as `$id = $_POST['selected_id']`;

Comment: I don't know if you'll get this, but if you do, in the modal widow inside the form, I added php tags and did var_dump($_POST); and did $id = $_POST['selected_id']; and it printed this out: array(3) { ["resgroup"]=> string(4) "test" ["restype"]=> string(0) "" ["service"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Yeah, you should put your `var_dump` in the php file which is the `action` of the form instead of putting it inside the modal code.

Comment: So like this: <form class="well-small" action="<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>" but that didn't work. How should I would it?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No, the correct tag is `<form action="a-php-file.php" method="post">...</form>` and put the `var_dump` code in the `a-php-file.php` file. Of course, this `form` must be put inside the modal body (see my example code in the answer)

Comment: My current form and modal is in edit.php. Are you saying that I need to have a separate php file to send the var_dump?

Comment: So set the `action="edit.php"` and you can view the `var_dump` result **after** clicking the submit bottom. Remember to see my HTMl structure above.